# Secure WebSocket connection failing on secure IIS site with reverse proxy to Node server

Tags: node.js, iis, websocket

I have successfully secured our internal IIS site with a trusted certificate.  Everything looked good until I noticed my websockets were broken.  We rely heavily on them, so that is a deal breaker.

I have the front end site with a URL that looks like https://example.domain.local and then I have a backend Node server running and any calls to https://example.domain.local/api/* get reverse proxied to my Node server at http://example.domain.local:3009.  Notice my Node server is not secured.  Unless I absolutely have to, I would like to avoid the complexity of doing that.  I also have some image paths reverse proxied to my Node server and those work just fine.  I have an entry in my web.config for sending my wss://example.domain.local/ws calls to my Node server at ws://example.domain.local:3009.  That part I was basically just guessing, I could not find much info online about how to do that.  The error in the console says: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.domain.local/ws' failed:`.

Here is my full web.config file(I have swapped out the real URL for `example.domain`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
              <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-store, max-age=0" />
            </customHeaders>
          </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                 <rule name="WS reverse proxy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="wss://example.domain.local/ws(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
                    </conditions>
                     <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_EXTENSIONS" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="ws://example.domain.local:3009/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Static Assets" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy Thumbnails to Node Server" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^thumbs/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.domain.local:3009/thumbs/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy Images to Node Server" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^images/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.domain.local:3009/images/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy API Calls to Node Server" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^api/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.domain.local:3009/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="api/(.*)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
                <!--rule name="SSL" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="On" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://example.domain.local/{R:1}" />
                </rule-->
                <!--  this rule will route all requests through the index.html so React can load the requested URL correctly -->
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsTextHtml" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="^(.*?)\s" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding" enabled="true">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="AnchorTagsRule" preCondition="ResponseIsTextAnything" enabled="false">
                    <match pattern="href=(.*?)http://example.domain.local:3009/(.*?)\s" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="href={R:1}https://example.domain.local/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="FormTagsRule" preCondition="ResponseIsTextAnything" enabled="false">
                    <match pattern="action=(.*?)http://example.domain.local:3009/(.*?)\\" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="action={R:1}https://example.domain.local/{R:2}\" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsTextHtml">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsTextAnything">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/(.+)" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".*" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" />
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Rewrite,RequestRouting" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="200-399" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The first rule below (WS reverse proxy) will not work because it does not match the pattern. The matching URL of the rule pattern mainly matches the path part in the URL, that is, `ws/(.*)`

Comment: @YurongDai Sorry, I'm not fully understanding what you are saying.  Are you saying the match url should be changed from `wss://example...` to `ws/(.*)` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will get you out of the way, I just want to tell you that the first rule  clearly can't work. For example, if your website url is: `https://example.domain.local/ws/test?id=1`, then the matching part of the rule pattern should be `ws/test`.

Comment: OK, but how do I specify the `wss://` part to be matched then?  I want to forward all reguests starting wtih `wss://` to my node server that is `ws://...`

Comment: @dmikester1 Late but did you find any solution? Currently i have the same issue :/

Comment: @KevinV No, I never could figure it out.  We are stil unsecure on our internal app and therefore not able to use the camera on the ipads in the app.  I'm thinking of trying it out in Caddy to see if I have better luck.

Comment: Some simple configuration of HttpPlatformHandler can get rid of all those reverse proxy rules for you to host the REST API under `https://example.domain.local/api/` as an IIS application under the static site. You can learn from https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/